# Anti Aliasing - Alpha Image [Unity3D]

Tags: image, alpha

I have a system that removes the colour white (give or take a few shades), from an image and replaces it with an alpha channel. (The image is taken from the users phone camera, and tries to remove selected colouring)

This leaves harsh edges most of the time, and I want to know if it is possible to add some type of anti-aliasing on top.

The system works by taking in the image, and searching through each pixel data. If the pixel is white (or close), it will replace it with an alpha colour.

So I guess my question is, how do I make the edges less harsh. Thanks.

Comment: If you already have a beginning of the alpha channel, you can blur it 'into' the image, as many pixels deep as you think is necessary. A regular blur will smear into the white as well as into the image, but I think an "erode" algorithm should work.

Answer (score 0):

Anti aliasing is not what you are looking for. This takes care of effects caused by the limited resolution of your image. However, your problem is not related to resolution, you would still have it with infinite resolution.

What you need to do is when you find a white pixel, increase the transparency of the pixel itself and the pixels around it.

You can just include the four pixels immediately above, below, left or right of your white pixel, or you an choose any other shape, e.g. all pixels which lie inside a circle of given radius around the white pixel.

Also you can choose a function which determines how transparency is distributed over that shape. You can make everything half-transparent or you can decrease the effect towards the edges of that shape (though I don't think that this will be necessary).

Thus each pixel will receive transparency from several pixels around them. The resulting transparency must be computed from all these contributions. Simply multiplying them probably won't do, because you will have a hard time ever reaching alpha=0. You may however, interpret (255-alpha) as a measure of transparency, add all contributing transparencies and then convert back into alpha. Something like max (0, 255 - (255-a1) + (255-a2) ...).

It will be difficult to do this in-place, i.e. with just ony copy of the image. You might need an intermediate "image", where each pixel is associated with all transparency contributions from the pixels around it.